# Kubernetes pod security policies uid/gid ranges

Tags: security, kubernetes

I need to allow the ranges 0-1000 , and 6000-7000 to be used for application deployments , and forbid all others.

Does this configuration will prevent someone to exec into pod/container and can switch to some other uid/gid ?

Comment: What do you mean by allowing 6000-7000 for deployments? You control deployments through IAM in the cloud provider or by setting RBAC in case of on-prem kubernetes. Kubernetes security contexts work for volume mounts as described in the documentation <a href="https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/">link</a>.

Comment: the link is broken , im using on prem , security context work but how to enforce them selectivly

Comment: Use this link. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Comment: You interact with kubernetes via API which means you need to set RBAC for permissions. If you want to restrict furtherly access to the filesystem, you would use kubernetes restrictions. 

Given that we have specified kubernetes is an API, there is no need to enforce uid/gid because there will be no interaction with the server by itself.

Answer (score 0):

Linux does not normally permit non-root users to exec as other UID/GIDs without something like `sudo`. As long as you also limit capabilities, `privileged`, privilege escalation and unsafe mount types, you can be fairly certain your pods will only run with processes as the UID/GIDs that you specify.

Comment: yes but for example ningx or apache running as uid 0 , and you exec into the pod and then switch to some other uid? or create another user inside container with some other uid and then switch to that one

Comment: Another way would be to make sure your container does not use root by default. Instead you declare some other user. Do that in the dockerfile.

Comment: If you apply a PSP that enforces UID ranges, you will not be able to run Nginx or Apache as UID 0. You will also not be able to create any users as a non-root user. The issue with defining the user in the Dockerfile is that it does not stop you from changing the user to root at run time (via the Pod spec), unless you have a PSP.